# error in ubuntu bash:. ./setenv.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, microcontroller, esp32

i am setting environment in ubuntu terminal for eclipse and running this command 
. ./setenv.sh
but its showing an error.

bash:. ./setenv.sh: No such file or directory

how it should be resolve ?

Comment: What's in that script?  Without knowing its content, it is hard to guess what is going on.

Comment: its for setting an environment for eclipse for ESp32

Comment: Can you also post the output for 1) $ pwd and 2) $ ls

Answer (score 0):

The error simply says, that within your current directory, there is no file `setenv.sh.`

If you have the location of the script in your `PATH` environment variable, simply call `setenv.sh`, without the leading `./`, because its meaning is "in the current directory".

Otherwise, locate `setenv.sh` via `find ~ -name setenv.sh`, and make sure you are within the correct folder, before you call `./setenv.sh`